# Bash is printing additional value along with process id

Tags: bash

I have the below line of code to print the PID of a puppet process:

```
processid=$(ps -eaf | grep -i no-daemonize | grep -v color | awk '{print $2}')
```

When I run this print the variable , it works fine and gives me the process of correctly

```
echo $processid
17128
```

However when I put this in a bash script, it prints two values:

```
17128 27438
```

What's the second value and how to remove it from the results??
Any help is appreciated

Comment: If `grep -v color` is to filter out `grep` from `ps` output, that'll only work if whatever grep alias you're using in your shell is also used in the script.

Comment: have you tried using `pidof`? pidof -- find the process ID of a running program.

Comment: Perhaps `grep -v grep` instead of `grep -v color` ?

Comment: If that doesn't work, then troubleshoot by changing the awk to `print $0` and see what other process keeps leaking through.

Comment: `grep -i no-daemonize | grep -v color | awk '{print $2}'` can be written as just one command: `awk '(tolower($0) ~ /no-daemonize/) && !/color/ {print $2}'`. You're probably getting 2 values when you put it in a bash script because now you're running 2 processes - the original one and your bash script.

Comment: In general, grepping the process table is a bad idea. Just don't do it -- if you want to track a process, set it up as a service, so you can ask your operating system's service management system (systemd, upstart, runit, etc) to start it, stop it, restart it, report on its status, etc. for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ed, the scriot was indeed printing the pid of the script i was running, made the below modification and now it works :

```
idprocess=$(ps -eaf | awk '(tolower($0) ~ /no-daemonize/) && !/color/ {print $2}')
```

this gives me only the pid of the process i need to filter.

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. Glad you're making progress with your problem and that you actually posted some code that was not working (and is now working). Don't forget to accept your own answer after (48?) hrs wait, to gain valuable reputation points. But, before posting more Qs here, please read https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask . Also please realize that the expected use of S.O. is that you post a well researched Q, and that readers post their answers  Request for clarification should usually result in improvements to your Q and not responses as another comment. ....

Comment: You're doing just fine for a first Q.  In any case, welcome and good luck!